# Are there drawbacks to implementing onClickListener for each ListView row instead of onItemClickListener?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

It would be more convenient for me to register a unique `OnClickListener` for each row in the `ListView`, but I want to be sure that this is an acceptable practice.  My [current design](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9721849/403455) is a rather convoluted way to separate the concerns of the `OnClickListener` from each row type.

The reason for this is that I have multiple classes of rows in the `ListView`.  Each class has a completely different responsibility and behavior.  For example, consider a `ListView` that can contain both sub-categories and book titles.  If a book title is clicked, a new activity should start that shows the cover image.  If a sub-category is clicked, a new list of books and categories is displayed.

I'd like the row itself to maintain knowledge about its own identity and responsibility rather than having to leak the knowledge about each row to be maintained by the implementer of `onItemClickListener`.

I'd also like to know what the performance implications are of doing this vs. implementing my own logic to figure out how to handle the click.

Are there drawbacks to implementing `onClickListener` for each `ListView` `ArrayAdapter` row instead of `onItemClickListener`?  I'm looking for *concrete data* and *specific drawbacks* rather than vague recommendations.

Should I expect *memory use*, *initialization time*, or *steady-state speed* (like scrolling through the list) to be significantly affected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't explain why you would need separate click listeners for each row, but I would recommend against it. Take a look at using `View.setTag(Object)`/`View.getTag()` to pass row-specific custom data by which you can customize the response of a (shared) click listener.

**EDIT**

I see from your example why you want different `OnClickListener`s attached to your rows. I was under the impression that you wanted a separate `OnClickListener` instance for each row. (That was my main reason for recommending against this.) If you have two types of rows (categories and titles) and hundreds of rows, you need only two kinds of responses, not hundreds of them. I also understand the point about separating concerns.

Nevertheless, I think overriding `ListActivity.onListItemClick()` (or calling `ListView.setOnItemClickListener()` if you aren't using a `ListActivity`) would be cleaner and less likely to interfere with the operation of the list view. You can use a delegate pattern for this, as follows.

Define an abstract class or interface:

```
public interface MyClickHandler {
    public void onItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id);
}
```

Then create one instance of an object that implements this interface for each *type* of row data (not one instance for each row). In your adapter, use `setTag(Object)` to initialize the tag for each row to the appropriate `MyClickHander` instance. In your `ListActivity.onListItemClick()` override, use this logic:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Object tag = v.getTag();
    if (tag instanceof MyClickHandler) {
        ((MyClickHandler) tag).onItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    } else {
        // default processing (if any)
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 and thanks so much Ted for the detailed response.  Do you by any chance have any data, or recommendations in the Android API that justify your recommendation against one listener per row, or are you basing this on more of a hunch?

Comment: One thing to watch out for with the tag-based solution is ensuring that you are updating the tag on every `getView()`/`bindView()` call. The classic "view holder" pattern only sets the tag when the row is inflated, but that is because the "holder" only holds things tied to the UI (e.g., widgets in the row). In the pattern described here, the tag needs to hold onto things that are tied to the model data and therefore will change with each position. Still, I would recommend something like this over using individual click listeners per row.

Comment: Ted, see my [follow-up Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9721790/403455) that describes my preferred way to separate concerns that doesn't involve `instanceof` and type information leaking into the `onListItemClick` methods.  The reason for this question you've answered is not to ask how to do this, but to ask the consequences of registering individual Row listeners.

Comment: @glenviewjeff - The approach you outlined in your follow-up Q&A has knowledge of the the UI leaking into the model. There's less separation of concern than in the approach I outlined. I agree that the use of `instanceof` is a bit off-putting, but that's forced on this approach by the anonymous nature of view tags. (If one could assume that non-null tags are always instances of MyClickHandler, then `instanceof MyClickHander` could be replaced by `!= null` and a cast. (Still not clean, but perhaps less dirty.)

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for pointing out the critical role `getView() / bindView()` have in this approach. I alluded to that in my answer, but it was far from clear.