# How can I eliminate the dependency from of a ListView's onItemClick/getView and its row types?

Tags: android, listview, dependencies, dry, separation-of-concerns

As a simplified example, consider a `ListView` that can contain both sub-categories and book titles.  If a book title is clicked, a new activity should start that shows the cover image.  If a sub-category is clicked, a new list of books and categories is displayed.

A `Row` interface is defined as follows.

```
interface Row {
   void onClick();
   void draw(View v);
}
```

I would like to know how to prevent a dependency from the `ListView`'s `ArrayAdapter` as well as from the implementer of `onItemClickListener` on the `Row` implementers (e.g.,`Book` and `Category`).

One of the forces driving this requirement is the "don't repeat yourself" (DRY) principle: the `ArrayAdapter` implementation does not need to change when new row types are introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive my chicken-scratched "UML" below, but here's how I do it.

```
class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row<?>> {
...
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = listViewRowViewRecycler.getView(convertView);
        rowProvider.get().getRow(position).draw(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

The implementer of `OnItemClickListener` has a method like this:

```
void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int rowIndex, long rowId)
{
   rowProvider.onItemClick(rowIndex);
}
```

Then `RowProvider` has a method like this:

```
void onItemClick(int rowIndex) {
    rowList.get(rowIndex).onClick();
}
```

Then the `Row` interface has a method with signature `void onClick()` and there are `Category` and `Book` implementations of `Row` that provide the necessary behavior.

[image: UML Diagram]

Comment: Now a Row needs to know about clicks and what to do about them. Why should Category or Book know anything about the UI?

Comment: `Row` implementers need to provide a method for assisting with display as well as what to do when they are selected.  Those two responsibilities are their sole purpose.  Would it help if you thought of them as being named `CategoryRow` and `BookRow`?

Comment: Ah. I was under the impression that Category and Book were model classes, not UI classes. Be that as it may, in the usual Android architecture, displaying the data and responding to events are separate concerns. You've now conflated them. What would you do if in another context you need to have a list view of the same items but with different responses? From how I understand your architecture, you'd need an entirely new Row class hierarchy that would duplicate the presentation logic just to have different `onClick()` responses.

Comment: @TedHopp `Row`, `Category`, and `Book` could certainly be partitioned into two trees: a `RowClickHandler` and a `RowDisplayer`.  I think designing this is out of the scope of the original question.  There is nothing inherent in the design that prevents this, and certainly nothing that requires duplicating any logic.  If you want, post a follow-up question about either or both of these issues and I'll answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use the setTag/getTag methods on each item's View in the list - this allows you to attach the 'Book' or 'Category' to its appropriate row.

For this to work each of the 'listed' items should implement a common interface that has an appropriate method to be called when it is clicked.

For instance:

```
interface Selectable {
    void onSelected();  // Add parameters if necessary...
}
```

In your list adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
    View itemView;  // Logic to get the appropriate view for this row.

    Selectable theObjectBeingRepresented;
    //
    // Logic to assign a Book/Category, etc to theObjectBeingRepresented.
    // In this example assume there is a magic Book being represented by 
    // this row.
    //
    Book aMagicBook = new Book();
    theObjectBeingRepresented = aMagicBook;

    // If all objects that will be contained in your list implement the 
    // 'Selectable' interface then you can simply call setTag(...) with
    // the object you are working with (otherwise you may need some conditional logic)
    //
    itemView.setTag( SELECTABLE_ITEM_KEY, theObjectBeingRepresented );
}
```

Then when an item is clicked:

```
void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int rowIndex, long rowId) 
{ 
   Selectable item = (Selectable)view.getTag( SELECTABLE_ITEM_KEY );

   // Depending on how you are populating the list, you may need to check for null
   // before operating on the item..
   if( null != item ) {
       item.onClick();  // Appropriate implementation called...
   }
}
```

A bit more detail on the setTag method: 
[setTag documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Hope this helps...

Comment: In this design, the types have leaked into the ListAdapter: `Book aMagicBook = new Book()`  This doesn't separate the concerns as requested, does it?

Comment: I put the allocation of a new Book for the example.  This part of the logic would depend on where he is getting the actual data from and how its being displayed.  If he has some list of all 'Selectables' then simply calling setTag(...) would do the trick.  

I would imagine though that when he is populating the view he will need to know what is actually being displayed.

Comment: Right, but doesn't the example break the separation of concerns constraint?  It's definitely possible to separate the list population code from the ArrayAdapter class because that is how I implement it.  I'll elaborate in my answer.